PowerShell 2 different arrays
I have an $array1 that is docker containers and image names.
$array2 is a list of active pull requests from Azure Devops.
I have attempted numerous variation of the code below.
I cannot seem to figure out the correct way to items from $array1 if they are not in $array2.
Master and Develop must always be removed.
I need all of the items removed from $array1 that are in $array2
$array1 = docker ps -a --no-trunc -f name=myWEAPS* | ForEach-Object { "$(($_ -split '\s+',25)[1,-1])" }
$array1 = $dockerCons[1..($dockerCons.Length - 1)]

$array1 = 'myserver:1517 myserver7998', 'myserver:1515 myserver7990', 'myserver:1514  myserver7999', 'myserver:Master', 'myserverS8003', 'myserver:Develop myserver8002'

$array2 = '1517' , '1518'
$reg = [regex] '[7][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

foreach ($dockerCon in $array1) {
    #Write-Host $dockerCon -ForegroundColor Gray
    if ($array2 -notcontains $dockerCon -and $dockerCon -match $reg) {
        Write-Host "`t"$dockerCon -ForegroundColor Red
    } 
}


Instead of using -notcontains try using -notmatch with a regex OR pattern, -notcontains is specifically to check if an item does not exist in an array but has to be an exact match.
# adding Develop and Master here since as stated must always be removed
$array2 = '1517', '1518', 'Develop', 'Master'
$matchPattern = '7[0-9]{3}'
# make a regex OR pattern
$notmatchPattern = $array2 -join '|'

foreach ($dockerCon in $array1) {
    if ($dockerCon -notmatch $notmatchPattern -and $dockerCon -match $matchPattern) {
        Write-Host "`t"$dockerCon -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

This would output the following items from $array1:
myserver:1515 myserver7990
myserver:1514  myserver7999


two suggestions: 1. $NotMatchPattern = $array2 + 'Master' + 'Develop' -join '|' because $Array2 is generated dynamically so this will add "Master" and "Develop" regardless of the contents. 2. piping $array1 to Where-Object or using .Where() for better readibility if performance is not the most important
